# How to delete any date separated by comma in input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to delete Any date from dates string separated by comma in input field.

I'm able to delete last date but what if i want to delete any date form middle position
For example
 Delete last date from input field it's working fine.
 Now Try to delete first,second,third date it's from input field it's not working.[image]
External link to jQuery ui css file

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

Input field

```
<input type="text" style="width:100%" id="dates" value="2016-11-16,2016-11-17,2016-11-18,2016-11-19,2016-11-26
">
```

External link to js files

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Working js code

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Input field selector on key up event
    $('#dates').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
        // Split string into array
      var datesString=$(this).val().split(",");
      // Create Empty Array
       dates=[];
       // Remove last element from array
      for(var i=0 ; i<datesString.length-1;i++){
       dates.push(datesString[i]);
      }
      // Set dates In input field
       $(this).val(dates);
       // after adding dates in input field add focus
       $(this).focus();

    }
    });
});
</script>
```

Working example in
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04cfg5s3/)

[jsfiddle full working functionality](https://jsfiddle.net/Daulat/9sdamnnb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to delete from input dates in the middle depends of cursor position ?

In that case plain input it's bad choice.  People won't know whether to click backspace before or after comma inside input.

In this case plugins like [Tag-it](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html) will work the best.

@Edit ---

I don't know why I did it for you, but here you have my reproduce.
https://jsfiddle.net/fd1034rn/5/

I need just few lines of code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myTags").tagit({
            fieldName: "date",
            singleField: true
        });

        $('#myTags input:eq(0)').datetimepicker();

        //tests
        setInterval(function(){
            $("#val").text($('#myTags').tagit('assignedTags'));
        },200);
 });
```

It's almost finished, you will have to refine this a bit.

Comment: The use of `setInterval()` to poll every 250ms is a really bad idea. Is there no methods of tagIt raised when a selection is made that you can hook to?

Comment: Omg - thats just for tests... Inside document you have hidden input which is updated automatically by tagit... setintervel is just to show you how it works in the background - you can delete it :P

Answer (score 1):

A simpler method to achieve this would be to `split()` the string in the field by the `,` character on `blur`, `focus` and `change`, and remove all but the first item of the array, something like this:

```js
$('#dates').on('focus blur change', function(e) {
  $(this).val(function(i, v) {
    return v.split(',')[0].trim();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" style="width:100%" id="dates" value="2016-11-16,2016-11-17,2016-11-18,2016-11-19,2016-11-26">
```

*Update*

Given your [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Daulat/9sdamnnb), you need to remove the `onSelect()` logic as that is what is pushing all the selected dates in to an array and showing the combination in the input:

```
$(this).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    showAnim: 'slide',
    minDate: 0
})
```

Comment: It's working but  think from users perspective .if there is lots of dates and user want to delete only one date . How to delete only one date before cursor

Comment: In which case only allow them to select one date from the picker. I can't help with that as you haven't shown the date picker code

Comment: Remove the `onSelect` logic as that's what's enable multiple dates in the field: https://jsfiddle.net/9sdamnnb/4/

Comment: How can we get cursor position and delete 10 characters before cursor including comma 11

Comment: You should start a new question for that - although if that's how you want to solve this problem I would strongly recommend you don't as it's a very brittle way of doing it, and easily broken. What's wrong with either of the solutions I've shown?

Comment: that's great idea 3 question same problem

Comment: Well, why have you asked the same question 3 times? You've been given workable solutions every time

Comment: No i asked 2 times I'm going to ask 3rd time  "How can we get cursor position and delete 10 characters before cursor including comma 11"

Comment: Use `indexOf()` and `slice()`, however the reason people are giving you alternatives to that is because it's a *really* bad solution to your problem

Comment: Thanks for help. do you know any plugin for selecting multiple dates.

Comment: yeah but any plugin with more functionality.

Comment: @daulat Tagit provide you whole logic for deleting each date you want. You just need to update DatePicker to add new tags according to tagit api instead of pushing new date to array. And finnaly tagit also will create for you in the background input with comma separated all tags (dates) like yours, which you can send via form. My solution is more user friendly and easier to implement but you downvoted my answear